# Instabot unable to send multiple messages to user

Tags: python, instagram

I am setting up an instabot that picks a message from an array and sends it to the same user.
However, when testing only the first message gets sent and then the bot freezes.

```
messages = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
bot = Bot()
bot.login(username='test1', password='test1')

for message in messages:
    bot.send_message(message, ['test1'])
```

I expect the script to send the messages - `test1`, `test2`, and `test3` one after another
to the same user. Anyone has experienced the same issue? Perhaps is a thread issue?

This is the log

```
2022-10-18 23:51:13,875 - instabot version: 0.117.0 (api) - DEBUG - GET to endpoint: multiple_accounts/get_account_family/ returned response: <Response [200]>
2022-10-18 23:51:14,353 - instabot version: 0.117.0 (api) - DEBUG - POST to endpoint: qe/sync/ returned response: <Response [200]>
2022-10-18 23:51:14,592 - instabot version: 0.117.0 (api) - DEBUG - GET to endpoint: igtv/browse_feed/?prefetch=1 returned response: <Response [404]>
2022-10-18 23:51:14,592 - instabot version: 0.117.0 (api) - DEBUG - Responsecode indicates error; response content: ...
2022-10-18 23:51:14,592 - instabot version: 0.117.0 (api) - ERROR - Error checking for `feedback_required`, response text is not JSON
2022-10-18 23:51:14,592 - instabot version: 0.117.0 (api) - INFO - Full Response: <Response [404]>
2022-10-18 23:51:14,592 - instabot version: 0.117.0 (api) - INFO - Response Text: <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. You just need to go to `api_login.py` (This is a file in this InstaBot library) and comment out line 163 which says

```
check_flow.append(self.igtv_browse_feed())
```

In general, for any module if you get 404, just comment it out and run. Also, make sure you always clear your config directory before running your script. Hope this helps.